# how can I upload a file to github server?

Tags: github

Is there a simple way to upload a file to github, if I made a minor modification, without creating a branch?

I'm trying to do something similar to a commit in svn.

Is there any way to perform this?

Comment: Do you have repo locally? And you are modifyinh there only right?

Comment: thanks for your quick answer!! I downloaded the whole project. And I'm only modifying there. However I don't thing there is a link between my local project and the server one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have repo locally and you modiied file you want to modify.

Open `gitbash` in directory where `.git` is present

execute

1. `git add .`
2. `git commit -m "Commit Message"`
3. `git push origin master`